# SoapUI error message

Tags: soap, soapui

I am sending a soap request using soapUI to fetch data from oracle 10g db. Soap UI successfully displays response when the db fetches results within 30 seconds.

But the real problem is when the db response exceeds 30 seconds, soapUI displays following error message :
Fault occurred while processing.

I have tried the below 3 scenarios :

```
1)  Increased the socket timeout to 1200000 
2)  Increased the timeout values in tomcat server config file (/conf/server.xml)
3)  Checked for any Null Pointer exception and found none.
```

Please help me to get success message in soapUI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jdbc test step?

Comment: Nope. Please let me know how to do jdbc test ? Thanks

Comment: You said "Using soapUI to fetch data from oracle 10g db". How did you test ?

Comment: Yeah actually the soap webservice is fetching the data from Oracle db. I'm using soapUi to test that service by sending requests and receiving responses

Answer (score 0):

There are many components between the SoapUI adapter and the database engine. Most of these will have a configurable timeout.

The listener on the database server will pass the query to the database engine - and the database engine itself will have some protection against long-running queries. It's quite likely that the database is killing queries that run over 30 seconds.

You can prove this by capturing a query from your application and trying the same query directly in the database administration tool. This will tell you why the query fails (if it fails.)

JDBC calls a component listening on the database server - this flow itself will have a timeout, which you can set at the JDBC level somewhere in your environment.